# When sending the configuration to the puppet agent, I get an error

Tags: linux, puppet, foreman

When sending the configuration to the agent, I get an error Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, no implicit conversion of String into Integer (file:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/accounts/manifests/init.pp, line: 24, column: 24) on node

---

```
init.pp

**# See README.md for details.**
class accounts(
  $groups                   = {},
  $groups_membership        = undef,
  $ssh_keys                 = {},
  $users                    = {},
  $usergroups               = {},
  $accounts                 = {},
  $start_uid                = undef,
  $start_gid                = undef,
  $purge_ssh_keys           = false,
  $ssh_authorized_key_title = '%{ssh_key}-on-%{account}',
  $shell                    = undef,
  $managehome               = true,
  $forcelocal               = true,
) {
  include ::accounts::config

  create_resources(group, $groups)

  create_resources(accounts::account, $accounts)

**  # Remove users marked as absent**
  $absent_users = keys(absents($users))
   user { $absent_users:
    ensure     => absent,
    managehome => $managehome,
    forcelocal => $forcelocal,
  }
}

_______________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I'm new to puppet and using it together with foreman

Puppet master version 7.2.0
Puppet agent version 6.27.0
Foreman version 3.4.0

All settings were made in Foreman. Manifests, like any other changes, were not made in the console.

Comment: I think what you're expecting is that $absent_users is going to be an array of user names? That error suggests that what it actually contains is an integer or an array of integers and user resource is complaining about that. What is "absents" you're using it as if it's a function call but it's not a standard Puppet function?

Comment: The problem appears to be that some of the data bound to class `accounts` do not have the expected form.  But you have not presented enough information for us to determine the specifics: not the data, not the identity of line 24 (since the code, as presented cannot possibly be the what Puppet is consuming), and not the definition of type `accounts::account` or of function `absents()`, which ever of those is the one that appears on line 24.  To give you meaningful help, we need a [mre].